# Get Original Link of Link to document using rest api in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using a link to document in document library. when i fetch all document using rest API I am not able to get the original link of Link to Document. How can i get that. Thanks